# Multithreading with Filesystem watcher and/or MSMQ wcf service

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to create a service which is basically responsible for the following:

1. Watch a specific folder for any new files created.
2. If yes , read that file , process it and save data in DB.

For the above task, I am thinking of creating a multi threaded service with either of the following approach:

1. In the main thread, create an instance of filesystem watcher and as soon as a new file is created, add that file in the threadQueue. There will be N no. of consumer threads running which should take a file from the queue and process it (i.e step 2).
2. Again in the main thread, create an instance of filesystem watcher and as soon as a new file is created, read that file and add the data to MSMQ using wcf MSMQ service. When the message is read by the wcf msmq service, it will be responsible for processing further

I am a newbie when it comes to creating a multi threaded service. So not sure which will tbe the best option. Please guide me.

Thanks,

Comment: yes the service will be in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, let me say that you have taken a wise approach to do a single producer - multiple consumer model. This is the best approach in this case.

I would go for option 1, using a [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) data structure, which provides you an easy way to queue tasks in a thread-safe manner. Alternatively, you can simply use the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) method to send work directly to the built-in thread pool, without worrying about managing the workers or the queue explicitly.

**Edit**: Regarding the reliability of `FileSystemWatcher`, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) says:

> The Windows operating system notifies your component of file changes
>   in a buffer created by the FileSystemWatcher. If there are many
>   changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow. This causes the
>   component to lose track of changes in the directory, and it will only
>   provide blanket notification. Increasing the size of the buffer with
>   the InternalBufferSize property is expensive, as it comes from
>   non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so keep the
>   buffer as small yet large enough to not miss any file change events.
>   To avoid a buffer overflow, use the NotifyFilter and
>   IncludeSubdirectories properties so you can filter out unwanted change
>   notifications.

So it depends on how often changes will occur and how much buffer you are allocating.

Comment: First of all thanks for the input. So in theory single producer is basically the FileSystemWatcher instance. How reliable is to use FileSystemWatcher ? Any idiea?

Comment: The producer is actually the thread on which the FileSystemWatcher is working. As for reliability, can you please clarify in which sense?

Comment: I mean if there are multiple files created at the same time how FileSystemWatcher  will behave?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Considering the reliability issue,is there any alternative to FileSystemWatcher that I should be using?

Comment: @user1213831: I'm not aware of any "official" alternative that is known to be reliably tested and recommended. I've found some amateur projects on various sites, but I don't know how good they are. Have you tried to test the `FileSystemWatcher` in a typical scenario? It might not be so bad.

Comment: No. But will give it a try and see how it goes. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider your demands for failure handling and sizes of the files you are sending.
Whether you decide for option 1 or 2 will be dependent on specifications.

Option 2 has the **avantage** that by using MSMQ you have your data persisted in a recoverable way, even if you may need to restart your machine. Option 1 only has your data in memory which might get lost.

On the other hand, option 2 has a **disadvantage** that the message size of MSMQ is limited to 4 MB per message (explanation in a Microsoft blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages.aspx)) and therefore only half of it when working with unicode characters,  while the in-memory queues are capaple of much bigger sizes.

**[Edit]**

Thinking a bit longer, I would prefer option **2**.
In your comment, you mention that you want to move files around in the filesystem. This can be **very** expensive in regards to performance, even worse if you move the files between different partions.

I have used the MSQM in multiple projects at work and am convinced that it would work well for what you want to do. A big advantage here would be that the MSMQ works with transactional communications. That means, that if for some reason a network or electricity or whatever failure occurs, neither your message nor your files get lost.

If any of those happen while you move a file around it could easily get corrupted.

Only thing I have grumbles in my stomach is the file sizes. To work around the message size limitations of 4 MB (see added link above), I would not put the file content into a message. Instead. I would only send an ID or a filepath with it so that the consuming service can find it and read it when needed.

This keeps the message and queue sizes small and avoids using too much bandwith or memory in network and on your serve(s).

Comment: Interesting. For option 1 , i can move the file in process to some other directory, keept that file untill the consumer thread has not completed the process. So does that mean that going with option 1 is better than 2? Although I am concerned using Filesystem watcher reliability for limited buffer size. As the first service is also a multi threaded service which creates file and save them to the folder.